# Android studio problem continue increasing counter

Tags: android, save, counter, continue

I am tring to make the part of a game where when you press the fab icon, a TextView, increase numbers. It starts from zero and increased by one.
I tried to save the number, in order to find it the next time, start the app and continue to increase it. 
I am new at saving and I searched it a little bit.

I wrote a code, where keeps the number when I close it and reopen it, but when I push the fab icon, it starts from the beginning and not from the number I have saved.
Perhaps I didn't understand very well the save code how it works. 
Can anyone help me? Thank you!!

My code in MainActivity is:

```
int newAge;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final TextView age  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                newAge++;
                age.setText(String.valueOf(newAge));
            }
        });

        //getting preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedAge = prefs.getInt("key", 0); //0 is the default value
        age.setText(String.valueOf(savedAge));

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("key", newAge);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply `savedAge` to `newAge`, because once you load your age from the `SharedPreferences`, you only apply the laoded age to the TextView and if you click on the button, the TextView will display 1 instead of your saved value.

```
int newAge;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final TextView age  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age);

    //getting preferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int savedAge = prefs.getInt("key", 0); //0 is the default value
    age.setText(String.valueOf(savedAge));
    newAge = savedAge; //set the age value, to further increase it by a button click

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            newAge++;
            age.setText(String.valueOf(newAge));
        }
    });



}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("key", newAge);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Try to read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/6580761), to get a better understanding of SharedPreferences in Android.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It helped me a lot! I will read it an hope to understand better how to save.
Can I ask you something more? Is there any way to save automate all the data for the next reopen? Can you suggest me any tuttorial? Thank you in advanced!!

Comment: I am glad I could help you :)
For your question, what do you mean with `all the data`?

Comment: I thought that there would be a way, where I could save all the data that user changes during the game.